# Search comparing and searching for strings in a varient table, trouble with correct construct for varient type

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

So I am following [the example in the documentation here](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/data-types-semistructured.html#examples) as I am trying to compare the json strings that I have uploaded from the tutorial, but am having troubles searching the variant type I uploaded my json file into.

So for the basic understanding I tried:

```html
USE DATABASE MYDB; 
USE WAREHOUSE MYWH; 


create table demonstration1 (
    id integer,
    array1 array,
    variant1 variant,
    object1 object
    );

insert into demonstration1 (id, array1, variant1, object1) 
  select 
    1, 
    array_construct(1, 2, 3), 
    parse_json(' { "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2" } '),
    parse_json(' { "outer_key1": { "inner_key1A": "1a", "inner_key1B": "1b" }, '
              ||
               '   "outer_key2": { "inner_key2": 2 } } ')
    ;

insert into demonstration1 (id, array1, variant1, object1) 
  select 
    1, 
    array_construct(1, 2, 3, null), 
    parse_json(' { "key1": "value1", "key2": NULL } '),
    parse_json(' { "outer_key1": { "inner_key1A": "1a", "inner_key1B": NULL }, '
              ||
               '   "outer_key2": { "inner_key2": 2 } '
              ||
               ' } ')
  ;
  
  select variant1  from demonstration1
  where variant1 contains('value');
```

error was that it did not recognize contains: 
SQL compilation error: syntax error line 2 at position 17 unexpected 'contains'.

This did not work either when I tried to use Array_contains:

```
ARRAY_CONTAINS('value'::variant, array_construct(variant1)) from demonstration1;
```

What should I be trying?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with the `select` statement? Do you trying to search in the entire JSON for the string "value" ?

Comment: When you say the ARRAY_CONTAINS() doesn't work, what did you actually try and what was the expected/actual result?

Comment: Yes, apologies for the error there. I was trying to search for all the instances of "value" and variations of. I was less specific in the second call 'hello', I was using a different data set. To be consistent I will update the question to have "value" and update the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for `contains` is a bit different. Try this instead:

```
select variant1 from demonstration1 where contains(variant1, 'value2');
```

Comment: Your syntax is accurate, but contains() is only for text of binary comparisons.  Neither the field or the contains string can be VARIANT.

Comment: It's cast to string implicitly. I tried the example before posting it, it works.

Comment: Thank you, I spelled the column name incorrectly in the question. This worked.